# MS Azure ads not showing correctly in the sidebar

Tags: bug, design

I don't know if this is the right place to post this, but I've noticed something strange. Every ad for Azure that comes up in the sidebar on Ask Ubuntu is cut off on the right side, taking some text with it. Opening the original image in a new tab shows the whole thing.

I don't know if this is just me, but I have still experienced it after multiple refreshes, and it's only with the ~2 Azure ads. I'm not sure if anything should be done about it, so I'm posting here to ask.

(Sorry if this question is unclear. I'm extremely tired :P)

Screenshots:

[image] 
[Original](https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11087206199491/Cloud_AzPlat_Banner2A_SB_EN_US_300x250_border.jpg)


[image]
[Original](https://cdn.atlassbx.com/FB/11087206199488/Cloud_AzPlat_Banner1A_SB_EN_US_300x250_border.jpg)

Comment: maybe it has something to do with this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites?cb=1

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: @Wayne_Yux that does make sense.

Comment: @MarcGravell I haven't had a chance to look.

Comment: @Zacharee1 to add context: a "fix" on ads was added and reverted yesterday; I wonder if you saw it in the "fixed" (read: broken in different ways) version

Comment: @MarcGravell I'll have to check later today. Thanks

Comment: @MarcGravell completely forgot to get back to you. No, the ads still aren't showing correctly.